# Change Mysql table from MyISAM to InnoDB

Tags: mysql

I have a project i have been running for a while that is getting a much larger database of around 6GB. 1 of the database tables keeps getting corrupted or is crashing more often now.

Table: 19 779 121   MyISAM  utf8_unicode_ci 5,4 GB

The table is so big as stores user statistics that each user can access on my website. so a lot gets written and read from that table all the time.

As i understand it the recommendation for big tables are to change MyISAM to InnoDB to keep this from happening as InnoDB can handle larger amounts of data faster and better?

If  the answer is yes i wonder how i could in the best way change the table to InnoDB?

i tried to do **ALTER TABLE my_table ENGINE = InnoDB;** but phpmyadmin just timed out when i did it and no change is done to the tables. I also tried to do this with SSH. i got the error **ERROR 2013 (HY000): Lost connection to MySQL server during query.** i have 5GB of ram on the server. each time i do this the ram when i watch HTOP is saying 14.5GB/5.00G before i get that error. Is it because i do not have enough RAM? If yes, what should i do?

And in general. Do Anyone got any suggestions in general on what to do with the table getting corrupt / crashing ?

Comment: do that in the command prompt/shell there is no timeout, ans 5 gig will take a lot of time

Comment: I tried doing that and i got the error **ERROR 2013 (HY000): Lost connection to MySQL server during query.** i have 5GB of ram on the server. each time i do this the ram when i watch HTOP is saying 14.5GB/5.00G before i get that error. Is it because i do not have enough RAM?

Comment: you have to run it direct at the server not over a connection. connect throuigh ssh and run it and let it run

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you can do is create a new table with the same structure but InnoDB as an engine. Then you can move your data from the myISAM table to this new table, chunk by chunk.